# Is there a way to move data from one Azure region to another Azure region without incurring costs?

Tags: azure

I have a resource group in an Azure geolocation, US West, and I want to set up a second resource group in another geolocation, US East.  I want to move my backups or snapshots from one region to the other without racking up fees for the transfer.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move data between Azure regions incurs Data-Out transfer costs - Data-In is free. This cost for West US is free for the first 5 GB and then $.087 per GB up to 10 TB.

[Bandwidth Pricing Details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/)